# How do i set a width: max-content in pdf wktmltopdf

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, wkhtmltopdf, wkhtmltoimage

I have a dynamic index inside my pdf which has the following design
[Design here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8U0z.png)
The first 2 rows are fine they come next to eachother but the last row wont be placed inline

But when i try to add width: max content on the left text so it will all be inline it wont work, i researched arround and found out that max-content does not work in pdf, not setting the width at all did not work either, how do i make it so it will be all inline

the html that i am using is:

```
<div class="relative w-full clear">
    <p class="bg-blue relative float-left pr-10px z-20">{{ $product->name }}</p>
    <p class="bg-blue relative float-right -mr-10px pl-10px z-20" style="width: 100px">PAGE 12 / 13</p>
    <hr class="z-10 absolute w-full">
</div>
```

Comment: can you please share the html producing that result? and can you explain better `the last one should also but in 1 row`?

Comment: I have updated the code for you

Comment: it took me a while to clearly understand the issue and only in the end I got what was going wrong. The third line "Connecting plate ends" has a content going on the next line because of word wrap. Probably a solution addressing that specific problem was better than what I provided below. Anyway it was easier to grasp if you shared the actual html of those lines instead of the template only. I also had to change some slight details to obtain the same exact result showing the line between the parts. That hints that maybe the html you used for that render isn't the exact same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hard part was trying to keep using the `float` approach while still having the `<hr>` in the middle of the two ends.

I did an effort trying to keep it as close as possible to what you already had instead of moving to the far superior Flexbox approach because I can't say how far some css standards work correctly with wkhtml2pdf.

So what I did here?

First of all I added a `.clearfix` class that replaces your `clear` one among the classes to which each line belongs to. Such custom class better styles each line on its own resetting the floating criteria.

Plus: I also added a `top` coord to the `<hr>` so that it places vertically in the middle of the line; and set the white background to the left and right parts so that they will hide underneath the line walking between the two ends.

```css
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="relative w-full clearfix">
  <p class="relative float-left pr-2.5 z-20 bg-white">Rectangular tabletop</p>
  <p class="relative float-right pl-2.5 z-20 bg-white">PAGE 12 / 13</p>  
  <hr class="w-full absolute z-10 top-1/2">
</div>

<div class="relative w-full clearfix">
  <p class="relative float-left pr-2.5 z-20 bg-white">Tabletop packaging</p>
  <p class="relative float-right pl-2.5 z-20 bg-white">PAGE 12 / 13</p>  
  <hr class="w-full absolute z-10 top-1/2">
</div>

<div class="relative w-full clearfix">
  <p class="relative float-left pr-2.5 z-20 bg-white">Connecting plate set</p>
  <p class="relative float-right pl-2.5 z-20 bg-white">PAGE 12 / 13</p>  
  <hr class="w-full absolute z-10 top-1/2">
</div>

<div class="relative w-full clearfix">
  <p class="relative float-left pr-2.5 z-20 bg-white">Incredibly long content expected not to word wrap</p>
  <p class="relative float-right pl-2.5 z-20 bg-white">PAGE 12 / 13</p>  
  <hr class="w-full absolute z-10 top-1/2">
</div>
```

Comment: Incredible that worked perfectly Thank you

Comment: I'm glad to hear also because I was a bit too harsh in my comments above.. you were clear in the question title and it's my fault being slow grasping the real issue.